# Django 1.8 python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django

I am inside my project's outer directory. When I try `python manage.py runserver`,it works but if I try to deploy my code and execute `heroku run python manage.py migrate`, it shows the following error -

```
(cenv) C:\Users\Machine\cenv\myproject>heroku run python manage.py migrate
 Running `python manage.py migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.6848
 python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

but when I input `DIR` it shows that `manage.py` is in the same directory.

```
   <DIR>          .
   <DIR>          ..
           59 .gitignore
   <DIR>          2015
   <DIR>          feature
          254 manage.py
   <DIR>          media
   <DIR>          myproject
           43 Procfile
          355 requirements.txt
           12 runtime.txt
          723 bytes
          12,963,143,680 bytes free


    (cenv) C:\Users\Machine\cenv\myproject>heroku run ls -al
    Running `ls` attached to terminal... failed
    !    App not found

    (cenv) C:\Users\Machine\cenv\myproject>heroku run pwd
    Running `pwd` attached to terminal... up, run.3539
    /app
```

Answer (score 4):

You must not be in the right directory on the Heroku server.  Try running `heroku run ls -al` to see what is in the current working directory.

Try `heroku run pwd` to see where you are.

You can also run `heroku run bash` to get a bash shell to poke around with.

Post what your first couple of commands return.

Comment: I've edited that part. It says there `app not found`. What could be the reason?

Comment: Just `do heroku run ls` and see what it returns.

Comment: Also, try `heroku run find`

Comment: `heroku run ls` does not return anything `heroku run find` just returns `.`

Comment: what about `heroku run find /`

Comment: That returns a lot of values(like hundreds). I'll add the last two values. /usr/share/doc/libssl-doc/demos/engines/zencod/hw_zencod_err.c.gz
/usr/share/doc/libssl-doc/demos/engines/zencod/hw_zencod.c.gz

Comment: I try `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic` or `heroku run ./manage.py collectstatic` (previously I applied `chmod +x manage.py` ) but my result is `can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` and I am in the current directory which is located `manage.py file` I don't understand the situation. Anything support would be appreciated :)

Comment: You need to ask a new question, not post your question in the comments of an almost-year-old question

Comment: @mikeb you have the reason. I give to you my apologies for it. I've posted another question in this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272067/deploy-static-assets-to-heroku-from-local-machine-cant-open-file-manage-py?noredirect=1#comment60171440_36272067 just in case that you can check and support me. I will be grateful with you.

Answer (score 4):

Change to the directory above `myproject` and call `heroku run python myproject/manage.py migrate`.

Comment: That helps! Thank u

Answer (score 3):

2 years later but for anyone coming here from google, I just had this same issue and fixed it.
When heroku return '.' as the only file in the directory it means you have not updated the git repository.

```
git push heroku master
```

hope this helps

Comment: 1 year later and you helped a lot